# Multiple JCheckBoxMenuItem selection in a JPopupMenu

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to implement such a JPopupMenu, that would allow to select several JCheckBoxMenuItem's. Basically I want that my popup menu do not close, after I had selected the first JCheckBoxMenuItem. I had an idea to override the hide() method from the Popup, but then I realized that the PopupMenuUI creates a Popup from the PopupFactory. So it appears to be not so simple. Maybe someone could help me with advice or even better with some sample ;)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Darryl's [Keeping Menus Open](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/09/12/keeping-menus-open/) should help.

Comment: This example works fine, if you place JCheckBoxMenuItems on JMenuBar. In my case, I use JPopupMenu. So, I must somehow trigger the "show(Component invoker, int x, int y)" method from a popupMenu on the previous coordinates.